# Load iframe to a div when working with local hard disk

Tags: javascript

I want to load sub-page.htm into div of index.htm when i click link.

All my files are located on my local hard drive: C:\MyPage\ ...

I don't want to use iframe, I need to use content of sub-page.htm between  ...  and put it into a div in index.htm.

I tried to load iframe using javascript, and then again using javascript i extracted iframe content, and i did put it into div. But javascript throws security error. I found at the interent it should work if files lays in the same domain, port and protocol. It should work on web server, but not when I launch my page from hard disk.

is it possible to run it from hard disk w/o security error?

Comment: Im have a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve here. Are you trying to "load" a file from the users local hard drive into the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for security reasons, the browser imposes limits on what JS can access from the local hard drive.

You will have to run a local http server in order to properly acess the data from the iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code on how to do this.  If this code doesn't work, it means that you have a permissions error reading to your directory and you will need to open the permissions to that directory and cascade the permissions down.

PS
I also have the code to render html, iframes, and pdfs.

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li class="ui-widget-content2" onclick="render_view('image','http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/server5500/9dbca/products/307/images/521/CM920PPeterGriffinLicense__48340.1410919117.1280.1280.jpg?c=2');">Render Image</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content2" onclick="render_view('image','/some directory to an image here!');">Render Image</li>

</ul>
<div class="change_me" id="change_me"></div>
```

JS

```
function render_view(type, data){
switch (type){
    case 'image':
        $('#change_me').html('<h3>Rendered Image</h3><img src="' +data+ '" ></img>').hide();
        break;
    case 'html':
        $('#change_me').load(data).hide();
        break;
    case 'html_iframe':
        $('#change_me').html('<h3>Rendered iFrame HTML</h3><iframe src="' + data + '" width="100%"; height="95%;";></iframe>').hide();
        break;
    case 'pdf':
        $('#change_me').html('<h3>Rendered PDF</h3><embed src="'+ data+'" width="100%"; height="95%;";></embed>').hide();
        break;
    default :
        alert('There was an error');
};
$('#change_me').fadeIn(1000);
};
```